# Laravel Dingo API always response "Not Found"

Tags: php, laravel, dingo-api

here's my code:

```
// api.php
$api = app('Dingo\Api\Routing\Router');
$api->version('v1', function ($api) {
        $api->get('test', function (Request $request) {
            return "test";
        });
}
```

```
// request
http://localhost:8000/api/test
```

i didn't set API_PREFIX.

and all of my dingo Route is not working.

please help.

Comment: have you tried  http://localhost:8000/api/v1/test ?

Comment: same result. i can't find any difference now.